# Error launching rails server (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I've been running this rails server for about a month now and after rebooting the computer (I was trying to add global environment variables on my mac) the server now kicks out this error when I run "rails s".  I've made sure that both localhost and the virtual domain are pointing to 127.0.0.1 as well.  As I said, before rebooting, this was working fine, but afterwards is when the error popped up.

```
=> Booting Unicorn
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-    4.8.3/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:604:in `pack_sockaddr_in': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:604:in `canonicalize_tcp'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:590:in `expand_addr'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:236:in `listen'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:809:in `block in bind_new_listeners!'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:809:in `each'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:809:in `bind_new_listeners!'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:138:in `start'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-rails-2.2.0/lib/unicorn_rails.rb:33:in `run'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/chris/bbplm/bin/rails:8:in `require'
from /Users/chris/bbplm/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/chris/bbplm/bin/spring:16:in `require'
from /Users/chris/bbplm/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

After removing spring from the gemfile, I bundle installed and tried re-running the server.  This is the error I received.

```
=> Booting Unicorn
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:604:in `pack_sockaddr_in': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:604:in `canonicalize_tcp'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb:590:in `expand_addr'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:236:in `listen'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:809:in `block in bind_new_listeners!'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:809:in `each'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:809:in `bind_new_listeners!'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:138:in `start'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-rails-2.2.0/lib/unicorn_rails.rb:33:in `run'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/chris/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:8:in `require'
from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try removing `spring` from your `Gemfile`, run `bundle install`, and then try starting your server. No idea what actually causes this, but this has worked for me in the past.

Comment: validate if you DNS works

Comment: Tried removing the gem and bundle installing.  Same error with a different stack trace.

Also, my DNS seems to be working fine in the system.  Do you have a specific way of checking it?  Going to all websites works fine.

Comment: I've rebuilt the environment in a Ubuntu VM and everything is working properly with the exact same code.  I really wish I could figure out why it's throwing this error.

Comment: Try explicitly going to http://127.0.0.1:3000, in case some merry prankster has defined `localhost` in your DNS as something other than 127.0.0.1 - it happens occasionally!

Comment: The rails app is expecting to see backboneplm.dev coming in.  I've checked my hosts file and both localhost and backboneplm.dev are pointing to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2):

check `etc/hosts`has `127.0.0.1     localhost`

This was my issue, although where and how it went i have no idea!